# Find Index of Array by NSDate?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to find out the index of an array by an NSDate.

Ill tried:

```
var sectionsInTable = [NSDate]()

let indexOfElement = sectionsInTable.indexOf(date) // where date is an NSDate in my sectionsInTable Array

print(indexOfElement)
```

But ill always get **false**

How is it possible to get the index of an NSDate from an array?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you expect to find date in `sectionsInTable` if you've initialized it to be empty?

Comment: That is just for example. There are still some NSDate() stored in that array.

Comment: A `NSDate` object is "precise". What contains exactly `sectionsInTables`? NSDate objects and you want the same date in the same day, same hour? You could use `indexOfObjectPassingTest:` and `isDate:equalToDate:toUnitGranularity:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have exact copies of `NSDate` objects, your code should work:

```
let date = NSDate()
let date2 = date.copy() as! NSDate
var sectionsInTable: [NSDate] = [date]

let indexOfElement = sectionsInTable.indexOf(date2)
print(indexOfElement)
//prints: Optional(0)
```

Comment: Thanks - ill found out that i have here a timezone problem too, need to fix that first and try that out later.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach should work fine. This code produces an index of 2:

```
let s = 31536000.0 // Seconds per Year
var tbl = [NSDate]()
tbl.append(NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 40*s)) // 0
tbl.append(NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 41*s)) // 1
tbl.append(NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 42*s)) // 2
tbl.append(NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 43*s)) // 3

let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 42*s)
let indexOfElement = tbl.indexOf(date)
```

The most likely reason that you are not getting the proper index is that your search `NSDate` has a time component that does not match the time component in `NSDate` objects in the array. You can confirm that this is the case by printing both objects, and verifying their time component.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Already found out that the library returns a different timezone - so my dates are not cleary the same. ill need to fix that first and try it out - but with your example ill trust you that it will work then.

Answer (score 0):

Since comparison depends on how deep you want to go with date time thing. I think you should just loop through your date array and compare if it's equal and return that index.